# Update Pandas Dataframe with Community Detection Labels

Tags: python, networkx

I have a dataframe (df_1) that looks as the following:

```
source    target                weight

name_1    field_of_study_1     0.005
name_2    field_of_study_2     0.01
name_3    field_of_study_1     0.0002
.
.
.
.
.
```

I have built an undirected weighted graph from it using Networkx API, using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_weighted_edges_from(df_1[['source', 'target', 'weight']].values)
```

After that, I have applied the API's community detection algorithm like the following:

```
import community
communities = community.best_partition(g, weight='weight')
communities_values = [communities.get(node) for node in g.nodes()]
```

Now, my final goal is to update the original dataframe (df_1 above) with the results of this community detection (community labels).

This is what I have tried so far:

```
df_1['community_label'] = 0
for key, community_label in communities.items():
    if key in df_1['source'].values.tolist():
        df_1.loc[df_1['source'] == key, ['community_label']] = community_label
    if key in df_1['target'].values.tolist():
        df_1.loc[df_1['target'] == key, ['community_label']] = community_label
```

I want to know if the above code does exactly what I want or if I need to change it and if it is the case, how to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to get the community for each `source` node. You can do it without element-by-element processing:

**Create the graph:**

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from community import community_louvain

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'source': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'target': [8,9,9,8,8,9,8],
    'weight': [1,2,1,3,2,1,1]
})

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_weighted_edges_from(df_1[['source', 'target', 'weight']].values)
```

**Get source communities:**

`communities = community_louvain.best_partition(g, weight='weight')`

**Create the column for dataframe:**

`communities_values = [communities.get(node) for node in df_1['source']]`

**Write the new column to the dataframe:**

`df_1['community'] = communities_values`

`df_1`

```
    source  target  weight  community
0   1       8       1       0
1   2       9       2       1
2   3       9       1       1
3   4       8       3       0
4   5       8       2       0
5   6       9       1       1
6   7       8       1       0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vurmux. This is what I was looking for.